# Mongodb query using $and operator does full scan while same query without doesn't

Tags: performance, mongodb, indexing, operator-keyword

I'm relatively new to Mongodb and I'm having trouble understanding why a query with the $and operator seems to do a full scan, while the same query without it doesn't.

My document looks something like this

```
{_id:"123456", labels : [{label:"beef", language:"en"}, {...}],...}
```

I have a compound index on label and language, however, explain shows very different results depending on whether I do

```
db.mycollection.find({ "labels" : { "$elemMatch" : { "label" : "beef" , "$and" : [ { "lang" : "en"}]}}}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "Complex Plan",
    "n" : 4,
    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 16701573,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 0,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 16701573,
    "nYields" : 130540,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 16283,
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

or

```
db.mycollection.find({ "labels" : {$elemMatch: { label:"beef" ,"lang" : "en" }}}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor labels.label_1_labels.lang_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 4,
    "nscannedObjects" : 4,
    "nscanned" : 4,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 4,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 4,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "labels.label" : [
            [
                "beef",
                "beef"
            ]
        ],
        "labels.lang" : [
            [
                "en",
                "en"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

Can anybody help me understand why?.

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Don't use `$and` unless it's actually needed as it can make it hard for the query analyzer to find the optimal index.